# Failed to issue method call: Unit squid.service failed to load: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ssh, vps, digital-ocean, squid

I am working with a developer on a VPS and we are getting this Linux error, but he is more familiar with PHP, so we are having some issues clarifying this error.

Can someone please shed some more light?

```
sudo ssh -i /root/ssh/digitalocean -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@162.243.87.18 'service squid restart' 2>&1
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  squid.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit squid.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: on your `162.243.87.18` server, there is no service squid (at least according to systemd).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the service is names "squid3" and not "squid", so

```
service squid restart
```

should be replaced with

```
service squid3 restart
```